# PyTorch: Dogs vs Cat dataset with datasets.ImageFolder

Tags: pytorch

I am new on PyTorch trying to create a TransferLearning model.

I am using [dogs vs cats dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats) from Kaggle.

I am using ImageFolder to load the data and it requires a folder for each classes. But the photos in the test folder are mixed.So I'm not able to separate the images on the test folder. What can I do to solve the problem apart from labeling all the test data with my hand?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom Dataset class and wrap it inside a dataloader in Pytorch.

This [link](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html) has great information on this topic

An overall structure to follow is

```
class Dog_and_Cat():
  def __init__(self, ...):
    ... # replace with a zipped list of image paths and labels (Cat or Dog)
    # You can use glob.glob
    # Overall ask how do I know the label of the image and install that reasoning in code
    # result is a zipped list like [("img1.jpg", 0), ("img2.jpg", 1)] where 0 and 1 represent Cat and Dog

  def __getitem__(self, idx): 
    #describe the func when indexing your class. This is where you open your image and do transforms and return it. 

  def __len__(self):
   # This is where you describe the length of the dataset. 
   # Ideally should return len of zipped list mentioned above.
```

You can init this class you just made instead of Image Folder and then put an object of that class inside the dataloader. This will solve your task

Sarthak